# PHP->VBA using COM object, works on my PC and does not work on windows server

Tags: php, vba, ms-access, com, report

Situation: open an MSACCESS report, output to PDF and download, using PHP:

1 - Initially I used the following approach that worked on my computer:

```
try {
    // Create a COM object for Access Application
    $accessApp = new COM("Access.Application") or die("Unable to instantiate Access");
    
    // Open the database
    $accessApp->OpenCurrentDatabase($databasePath);

    // Open the report
    $accessApp->DoCmd->OpenReport($reportName, 5, null,$filtro);
    // Set the output file path
    $outputFilePath = 'D:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sagesp\\reports\\PCT_'.$turma.'.pdf'; 

    // Export the report to PDF
    $accessApp->DoCmd->OutputTo(3,$reportName,"PDF Format (*.pdf)", $outputFilePath, false);
    $accessApp->Quit();
    unset($accessApp);
    ...
```

When I put it into production, Windows Server R2 2008, Office 2010. My PC is Win10, Office2019, the reports produced on Win Server did not fit on the page. Everything worked fine on my PC.

2 - Second approach, I tried this, i thought it controlled better and it was impossible not to work (how wrong I was :( )

VBA Function, works well in both Access (I tested)

```
Public Function ExportReportToPDF(ByVal reportName As String, ByVal filtro As String, ByVal turma As String)

    DoCmd.OpenReport reportName, acViewReport, , filtro, acHidden
    
    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, "D:\xampp\htdocs\sagesp\reports\PCT_" & turma & ".pdf", False

End Function
```

PHP

```
    $turma=$_GET['turma'];
    $rpt=$_GET['rpt'];
    $databasePath = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\sagesp\SAGESP-2023-24-AEPA.mdb';

    $reportName=$rpt;
    $filtro='turma="'.$turma.'"';
    $accessApp = new COM($databasePath) or die("Unable to instantiate Access");
    $result = $accessApp->Application->Run("ExportReportToPDF",$reportName,$filtro,$turma);
```

Once again, it works 100% on my PC, but it doesn't work at all on Win Server, tested with localhost and remote. The database on my PC is a copy of the one on the Win Server, my Office is 2019 and the other is 2010 and the OS is different, both have the extension=php_com_dotnet.dll in php.ini
I have the following error in the console: 'error:%20%3Cb%3ESource:%3C/b%3E%20Unknown%3Cbr/%3E%3Cb%3EDescription:%3C/b%3E%20Unknown' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.
When I comment the line that calls the function, I have no error.

I've been struggling with this for many days, wasted time, several solutions, shit from M$, some ideas ?, I've seen permissions, do I need to register an object?

some ideas on what the problem might be, please remember, I have limited control on the Win Server.
Thank you all

João

Comment: Instead of swearing against Microsoft, just read this old but still valid official statement about using Office on a server https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2 To make it short *"Microsoft does not recommend or support server-side Automation of Office"* because *"Office applications were never intended for server-side use"*.

Comment: Yup, Office doesn't do well on non-user accounts and this is explicitly unsupported. I've had some luck running the server program under an actual user account, but that requires some ability to configure the server. And that was far from stateless, expect trouble if your server needs to deal with more than 1 request per minute.

Comment: Is database split design?

Comment: No, and works well in my computer! It wasn't my choice to do things like this, sometimes when we work, we inherit things and we have to solve them, please spare me the moral lessons

Comment: I don't see any moral lessons here, just practical ones. This works badly because it's not supposed to work at all. One point I would make is that this situation is probably made worse by not developing in the same environment you're going to deploy to. Office 2010 and 2019 likely have significant differences. And then there's the ancient operating system on the server as well. I suggest making a VM which mirrors the 2008 environment (I'll spare you the speech on it being years past end-of-life, I'm sure you know it) and building your code using that. It's more likely to work when copied over

Comment: P.S. `I have the following error in the console`... do you mean a browser console? It's unclear what would be producing that. `because the scheme does not have a registered handler`...what scheme and handler are you referring to? It's not precisely clear how this would relate to Access or Office.

Comment: Also, is the production server running as x64 bits, or as x32 bits? This MATTERS HUGE and you have to install access/office as to the same bit size as what the web server is currently running as. I suggest you DO NOT use "any cpu" but force the project to x86 (x32 bits), and see if that works. As noted by multiple people here, automation of ms-access from a web site is a very bad idea, and such code is not thread safe, let alone realible. I suggest for a report to pdf, you consider using the SQL client side "report writer". This works without SQL server reporting services, and creates pdf's

Comment: Oh, ignore the "any cpu" remarks - I thought this was asp.net. However, the issue about bit size version of office matters (the bit size of Access has to match the running bit size of the web server.  So, if web server is running as x32 bits, then you install Access x32. If web server is running at x64 bits, then you have to install access x64 bits. So, check that your versions of Access match the bit size of the web server.....

Comment: Many thanks for the help, both machines 64bits, and i know this work sucks. the  error is related with the function and parameters (browser console). I work in a group of schools, and they have a complex and very old DB in access, the job is to have a web interface that allows all the dispersed schools to access and work on that DB, I told them right away that the reports were out of question.

Comment: Then maybe using `Sharepoint` is the right choice.

Comment: *"the reports produced on Win Server did not fit on the page"* Do you mean that the PDF pages don't show all the content properly?

Comment: To take a differnt route.  Does your access database change?  do you change it from the server?  How often do you update on the server?  The reason I ask is that you might have much better luck converting your mdb file to a proper SQLServer database and then connecting PHP just via PDO to do whatever reports you wish.  The conversion from mdb to SQLServer is well defined and supported by Microsoft.  You can use SQLServer express for free also.  Might just be a nice work around for you.

Comment: So, if your software is x64 bits, then did you install Office/Access x64 bits then? (the default install of office used to be x32 bits, up to about office 2016. After that, then newer installs default to x64 bit versions. So, yes, my points about matching the bit size between the 2 systems is STILL a requirement.

Comment: @Toby, the issue is the user not really much using the access database engine as much as they are using the Access report writer to output PDF files. Upgrade data to MySQL or SQL server solves zero here, since then what you going to render those reports with? Access is not the database, but JET or ACE data engine is the database. Ms-access can be used with MySQL, SQL server or whatever. Issue is the VERY able reporting system in Access that can output PDF files. Database not issue, but output of PDF and recreating those reports and outputing to PDF's is why this is being done this way.

Comment: Solved - the problem was always permissions, I went to the Apache service, logon and set one account with privileges. The code works well and quickly, let's see it in production now with some requests, if there are problems, I will restrict it to one report at a time, users will have to wait a few seconds, I will give news. many thanks